# Deleting .jar extension

Tags: file, jar

I got a .jar file and i found that the .jar extension (e.g. xx.**jar**) behind the name is a bit annoying (for me).

I want to delete the .jar extension behind the name by renaming it.

Will the file still work / open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide `.jar`  extension.
However, if you delete the extension, the file may not work.